# Using raphael, why won't the href attribute work while everything else does?

Tags: theming, javascript

I am having trouble getting Raphael to work in Drupal. Very bizarre problem however. I have a page that requires an SVG map with active links. I have created a custom tpl.php file for the page that will have the SVG. In it I put the link to raphael and the javascript for drawing the SVG. Everything is working well in my SVG except one thing. I have many shapes that each need a hyperlink. So I am using the 'href' attr which is part of the Raphael API. However, while my shapes are rendering perfectly, and all my other attributes (title, target, opacity, fill, etc.) are working, href comes up with something strange. It does put the svg shape inside "a" tags but the URL ends up in a second title tag within the shape. My code looks like this:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/libraries/raphael/raphael-min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body><blockquote></blockquote>
// after <?php print $page; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
var paper = Raphael('paper', 1699, 1316);
// all of my svg shapes in here. here's one example:
var circle_bg = paper.circle(973, 732, 8);
circle_bg.attr({
    title: "Click Me!",
    cursor: "pointer",
    href: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    target: "self",
    opacity: '.3',
    fill: '#000000',
    'stroke-width': '0',
    'stroke-opacity': '1'
}).data('id', 'circle_bg');
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

the output looks like this

```
<a xlink:show="self" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <circle cx="973" cy="732" r="8" fill="#000000" stroke="#000" opacity=".3" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 0.3; stroke-opacity: 1;">
       <title style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Click Me!</title>
       <title style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">http://www.w3.org/2000/svg</title>
    </circle>
</a>
```

I have also tried putting the javascript to draw the SVG in the node but with the same results. Also, my code works fine when it is not in Drupal.
Mind == Blown.
Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: have you tried using the raphael module. https://drupal.org/project/raphael

Comment: I read about that module and briefly tried it but I don't need it. I'm only calling Raphael on two pages of a large site, and directly (not from another module). I think I am going to have to use the .click() event. Thanks for taking a look.